# matching, then grouping list elements

Tags: python, list, parsing, python-itertools, pandas-groupby

I have parsed a text file pulling the relevant data. I then combined the variables(dlOrbit2, imageId3, imageStart4, imageEnd4)together to created a series of 4 strings in a list.

```
combined = str(','.join([dlOrbit2, imageId3, imageStart4, imageEnd4]))
strSplit = combined.split(',')
```

print strSplit

```
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']
['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:48:37']
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:12:53']
['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:54', '2016-10-26 13:13:13']
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
```

I would like match and group elements in the first column. So, 46284 x 4, 46288 x 6, 46290 x 2, 46291 x 4.  Within those groups I would like to have the earliest time from element 2 and the latest time from element 3. So desired output would be:

```
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']
['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:54:57']
['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:13:13']
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
```

This list will always be 4 elements, however the # of the grouping elements (first column) will always be changing.

I am going to export these results into a CSV file. However, I only need help with the above section.

Comment: have you tried to do anything? could you show us how far you've gone?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr i have tried for days, I just keep spinning in circles.  I really don't know the next step. I have tried to put in a dictionary, tried to compare and append.

Comment: yeah, just show us the code and we will see what went wrong.

Comment: how did you get this row: `['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:13:13']`?  The min time corresponds to 514628, but the max time corresponds to 514629.  So how did you decide that 514628 should be in column 1?

Comment: @BobBaxley that was an error on my part, I have to copy paste from one comp to another. i will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

dat = [['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:48:37'],
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:12:53'],
['46290', '514629', '2016-10-26 13:12:54', '2016-10-26 13:13:13'],
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']]

df = pd.DataFrame(dat).drop_duplicates()
df_times = df.groupby([0]).agg({2:min,3:max}).reset_index()
df_times.merge(df,on=[0,2])[[0,1,2,'3_x']]
```

Output:

```
0   46284   514607  2016-10-26 02:43:46 2016-10-26 02:48:39
1   46288   514626  2016-10-26 09:48:26 2016-10-26 09:54:57
2   46290   514628  2016-10-26 13:12:34 2016-10-26 13:13:13
3   46291   514738  2016-10-26 14:56:39 2016-10-26 14:59:06
```

Comment: This is a nice solution though all of the column name and ordering stuff feels a bit brittle. Note that pandas also would make saving to csv very easy with `DataFrame.to_csv()`.

Answer (score 1):

As a newcomer to Python myself, I would like to see examples with base python functionality before using Big Hammers.

If it could be done without module imports in less than dozen lines of code I would expect to learn that 1st.

perhaps manipulating lists of lists with double indexing wasn't understood?

```
combined = [['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'], ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'], ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'], ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'], ['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:48:37'], ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'], ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'], ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'], ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'], ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'], ['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:12:53'], ['46290', '514629', '2016-10-26 13:12:54', '2016-10-26 13:13:13'], ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'], ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'], ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'], ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']]

combined[0][0]    # double index
Out[28]: '46284'

combined[2][2:]   # slice
Out[29]: ['2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39']

max(combined[2][2:])    # duck type order comparison
Out[30]: '2016-10-26 02:48:39'
```

and why not def a function to use these basic Python tools on the input lists before the grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage on [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
data = [
    ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
    ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
    ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
    ['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
    ['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:48:37'],
    ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
    ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
    ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
    ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
    ['46288', '514663', '2016-10-26 09:53:46', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
    ['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:12:53'],
    ['46290', '514629', '2016-10-26 13:12:54', '2016-10-26 13:13:13'],
    ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
    ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
    ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06'],
    ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']
]


from itertools import groupby, tee
import pprint

res = []
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    it1, it2, it3 = tee(g, 3)
    res.append(next(it1)[:2] + [min(x[2] for x in it2), max(x[3] for x in it3)])

pprint.pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
[['46284', '514607', '2016-10-26 02:43:46', '2016-10-26 02:48:39'],
 ['46288', '514626', '2016-10-26 09:48:26', '2016-10-26 09:54:57'],
 ['46290', '514628', '2016-10-26 13:12:34', '2016-10-26 13:13:13'],
 ['46291', '514738', '2016-10-26 14:56:39', '2016-10-26 14:59:06']]
```

`for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0])` will group the consecutive rows based on the first column. It will return a tuples where first item is the key used for grouping and second is an iterator over the group items.

`it1, it2, it3 = tee(g, 3)` will split the group iterator to three iterators of which each will return exactly the same items. Finally the result is constructed by taking first two columns from first grouped item and running `min` & `max` over the two other iterators.